# Are there any recent resources on this variation of the Exchange Caro-Kann?

Tags: caro-kann

The variation I'm talking about is:

1. e4 c6
2. d4 d5
3. exd5 cxd5
4. Bd3 Nc6
5. c3 g6!? .

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 3. exd5 cxd5 4. Bd3 Nc6 5. c3 g6!?
```

I found it in an old book about the Exchange Caro-Kann but it's written without ideas, only a list of moves and for me it's not so useful. In general, I've found out by viewing that list of moves that it could be a sort of system: Black wants ... Bg7, ... Nh6, ... f6 followed in the future by ... e5 if White allows it, but I tried playing it on lichess and my execution was really bad; so I'm interested in the opening and curious about resources.

Comment: Exchange Caro-Kann is mostly about black light squared bishop - it's his worst piece by far. So one important idea is how to exchange it off. In these g6 systems it's common to delay castling and play Bf5 - idea being that if white takes, you take back with g-pawn and you have kingside pressure through open g-file. Sometimes, if white played imprecisely enough, you can also afford to play e5 without f6, converting to isolani structure. There were some masterclasses on youtube about this, I will try to find them later.

Comment: i have faced similar to this https://lichess.org/bAxsVoXj#24

Comment: There is GM Neiksans bootcamp about exchange caro-kann: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMGO2OOj33Y It's from white perspective, but he also explains ideas for black. Around 20minute mark he starts covering g6 systems, even though he uses a tad different move orders.

Comment: Interesting, I will check it out. Thanks.